# UITableViewCell subviews incorrectly positioned at first

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've made a subclass of `UITableViewCell` as so:

[image]

I'm using constraints to position my subviews, such as the switch.

The problem is that when I initiate the TableView the subviews, such as the switch, are positioned as if the cell were 320 px wide. The switches then moves (animates) to the right and are then positioned correctly. See image below.

[image]

I don't want this animation and the subviews should be positioned correctly when the TableView shows. I do nothing in the `awakeFromNib()` and `layoutSubviews()` (which I suspect maybe i should?).

The

**EDIT**

A gif of whats happening:

[image]

The constraints:

[image]

Comment: Can you show a GIF?

Comment: @Michael show your constraints for the cell.

Comment: I have now edited the post with a GIF and the constraints.

Comment: Notice something similar happening with the Brödrost text. I think all of the frames are being animated in. Can you show the code you're using to create this animation?

Comment: I've haven't created any animations, this happens by default